# Elisp function to remove commas in the region

Tags: region, string

I'm learning writing Elisp functions to perform small tasks and get to a place where executing a function on the region will replace it with the value returned by the function.

Below is a short function that aims to split the region text by commas and and concatenate the resulting substrings.

The code fails with `Wrong type argument, characterp` etc. After fixing this function, how can it be modified so that the string stored in `final` *replaces* the region?

```lisp
    (defun myconcat()
      "Split selected buffer and concatenate all words."
      (interactive)
      (progn 
        (setq x (buffer-substring (mark) (point)))
        (setq final "")
        (setq list (split-string x ","))
        (while list
          (setq final (concat final y)))))
```

EDIT: Added image from running function. Strangely, the function seems to be working on an old selected buffer, but not what I currently selected.[image]

EDIT: Another image with running `myconcat` after relaunching emacs

[image]

Comment: Can you show a small example with the contents of the buffer before and after? Do you really want to limit the portion of the buffer to be processed between the mark and the point, and then replace the *whole*  buffer contents with the result?

Comment: I want to replace the entire buffer that's selected.

Comment: Since you accepted @Drew's answer, I take it that you want to replace the selected portion of the buffer (i.e. the "region"). The "buffer" is the whole thing. Terminology is important. Please check the documentation with `C-h i g(emacs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't a great one for this site.  Instead of "Please debug this for me" you should ask a simple, specific how-to question.

Anyway, this will get you started.

```lisp
(defun myconcat(start end)
  "Split region on `,' chars and concatenate the substrings."
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((x      (buffer-substring start end))
         (final  "")
         (y      (split-string x ",")))
    (while y
      (setq final  (concat final (car y))
            y      (cdr y)))
    (message "FINAL: %S" final)
    (delete-region start end)
    (insert final)
    final))
```

I'm assuming you really want to replace the active *region* (the selected text), not the whole *buffer*. You say "selected buffer", which doesn't mean anything (unless the whole buffer is selected).

If you really want to replace the whole buffer by the selected text with its `,` chars removed, then just replace `(delete start end)` by `(delete (point-min) (point-max))` in the code here.

Things to note:

1. You never defined `y`.  Presumably your vars `list` and `y` were meant to be the same.
2. No need for `progn`. The body of a function is an implicit `progn`.
3. Don't use global vars (especially undeclared - no `defvar`). Use `let` or `let*`.
4. Use the `interactive` spec to give you the region limits.
5. `split-string` returns a list of substrings.  You need to iterate over that list, which means provide a substring to `concat` in each iteration.
6. Your loop never diminished the list of substrings.
7. You never deleted the original region or inserted the calculated text.

This is a bit better - the above tried to retain as much as possible of your approach, so you could more easily see the fixes.

```lisp
(defun myconcat(start end)
  "Split region on `,' chars and concatenate the substrings."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((final  ""))
    (dolist (str  (split-string (buffer-substring start end) ",")) 
      (setq final  (concat final str)))
    (message "FINAL: %S" final)
    (delete-region start end)
    (insert final)
    final))
```

The answer above was accepted. But if what's wanted is really just to remove the comma chars (`,`) in the region then there are better ways.  Here's one:

```lisp
(defun remove-commas-in-region (start end)
  "Remove the commas in the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region start end)
      (goto-char 1)
      (while (search-forward "," nil t) (replace-match "")))))
```

Comment: Your function prints the message in the command area. Also, I don't see the strings being concatenated. Wonder if I am missing something?

Comment: In general, neither your code nor your question is very clear. Normally I'd probably vote to close it as not being specific and clear, but here's a freebie for a newbie. Next question, please try to be narrow/specific: "How can I do XYZ?"